# PHP not uploading images but the mySQL query updates

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a blog with image upload basically.

Here is my add_post function:

```
function add_post($title, $txt_content, $img_content, $tags, $file_temp, $file_extn){
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    $txt_content = mysql_real_escape_string($txt_content);
    $tags = mysql_real_escape_string($tags);
    $file_path = 'simpleblog/resources/images/'.  substr(md5(time()), 0, 20) . '.' . $file_extn;
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` SET
                        `tag_id` = '$tags',
                        `title` = '$title',
                        `txt_content` = '$txt_content',
                        `img_content` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) ."',
                        `date_posted` = NOW()");
}
```

Here is the php script for add_post.php

```
<?php
include 'resources/init.php';

    if (isset($_FILES['img_content']) === true){
    if(empty($_FILES['img_content']['name']) === true){
        echo '<script type = "text/javascript">window.alert("Please pick a file!");</script>';
    }   else    {
        $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
        $file_size = $_FILES['img_content']['size'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['img_content']['name'];
        $file_extension= explode('.', $file_name); 
        $file_extn= strtolower(end($file_extension));
        $file_temp = $_FILES['img_content']['tmp_name'];

        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $txt_content = $_POST['txt_content'];
        $tags = $_POST['tags'];

        if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true && isset($_POST['txt_content']) === true){
            add_post($title, $txt_content, $tags, $file_temp, $file_extn);

            $post_id = mysql_insert_id();
            header("Location: index.php?post_id=" . $post_id);
            exit();
        }else if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed)=== false){
            echo '<script type = "text/javascript">window.alert("The only file type allowed are .jpg, .gif, .png");</script>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The mySQL database is updated with the image file's name. However, it is not moving the uploaded file into the `simpleblog/resources/images/` 
what is the problem?

Comment: Check "images" folder permissions... Is it writeable?

Comment: Did you check for permissions in this directory 'simpleblog/resources/images'

Comment: i think the problem is with the `PATH`.

Comment: @Cole another thing(although not very sure in this case) try == instead of ===

Comment: @Deadlock, Hanky Panky ㇱ, jogesh_p I checked it, the folder is writable!

Comment: @swapnesh Its a boolean, doesn't it require === instead of two, regardless, I'll give it a shot

Comment: from root where is add_post and where is your upload directory?

Comment: @HydraIO It is calling in from \simpleblog\resources\func\functions.php, I have done the same with my other site, it worked. This is the first time I'm implementing the image upload code along with a blog.

Comment: I fixed it, the PATH was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

At the first, this check of type is not right:

```
 $file_name = $_FILES['img_content']['name'];
 $file_extension= explode('.', $file_name); 
 file_extn= strtolower(end($file_extension));
```

if I upload file with name `image.php.jpg`, your check say this is an image, but I send php-file, and can request this file as php-file.

At the second, your function add_post has the parameter `$img_content`, but in the function call you ignore it:

```
 add_post($title, $txt_content, $tags, $file_temp, $file_extn);
```

And the file path in the **move_uploaded_file** function must have your site root path